# ASP/.NET to connect MySQL Server without using ODBC or any driver?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, .net, asp-classic, odbc

In `Classic ASP` or `.NET`, is there a way to connect `MySQL` without using, for e.g, `MySQL ODBC Driver` or `Any Driver` which needs to be installed on the Server, assuming i'm not an admin or not having any permission to install anything?

Comment: You will need to install the drivers any how. Web service too will fetch data form the your `MySQL` so this too will need drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Download the MySql.Data.MySqlClient dll from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html) before select  Platform .net/mono from dropdown list

add reference to your project. you are done.

its same as System.Data.SqlClient.

I hope it will help you

If you need documentation [Click Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html)

Comment: So it needs to download and install something on server anyhow, right?

Comment: yes you need to add that dll to your project. but this not driver just add that dll.

Comment: Project? You mean just to put/upload the file? No need to install anything on the Server by the admin?