# Is it possible to connect to a MySQL DB (on a Linux box) via PowerShell without any extra connectors/plugins/etc?

Tags: mysql, windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a MySQL database on a Linux machine that I would like to query from powershell v2; but I don't want to install any extra software on my Windows machine to do so. Is this possible?

If there isn't a way to do this, is there a way to "enable web services" for MySQL, so I could just connect like so:

```
New_WebServiceProxy -uri http://myserver/path/to/webservice/?wsdl
```

If I need to, I can modify the MySQL server; but I cannot modify the client that is trying to connect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP/.NET to connect MySQL Server without using ODBC or any driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755664/asp-net-to-connect-mysql-server-without-using-odbc-or-any-driver)

Comment: Flagging this as a duplicate because PowerShell is built on .NET, so the previous answer applies.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to install an ODBC provider for MySQL. See https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/dotnet/#ODBC.NET

MySQL has no built-in "web service" that I'm aware of - the idea of one sounds like a massive security hole waiting to be exploited.

Your only other option is a command-line MySQL client, but that would still violate your "no extra software" rule - if you're going to break that, you may as well do it right and go ODBC.